# How to access array elements from derrived class

Tags: kotlin

I have classes:

```
class A { MutableList<B> array1 = mutableListOf() }

class B { }

class Ba : B { MutableList<C> array2 = mutableListOf() }

class C { var name: String }
```

In my main function i did:

```
val itemA = A()
val itemBa = Ba()
itemBa.array2.add(C("name"))
itemA.array1.add(ItemBa)

for(arr1 in itemA.array1)
   for(arr2el in arr1.array2)
      print(arr2el.name)
```

But when i try to print elements from array2 through itemA element i get error Unresolved Reference, as if i can't get array2. But adding element to array2 worked fine. Is it possible to do it this way or whats the best approach to do something like this?

Comment: It's either Java or it's Kotlin. It's not both.

Answer (score 0):

```
MutableList<B> array1 = mutableListOf()
```

contains `B` elements.

```
class Ba : B { MutableList<C> array2 = mutableListOf() }
```

The `array2` list is defined for `Ba`.
The signature of `B` **doesn't expose members or methods**, so you cannot expect this to work.

```
val itemBa = Ba()
itemBa.array2.add(C("name"))
```

Here insertion works fine because you're working with `Ba` signature, which exposes its member `array2`.